# Check if user has access to Domino server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to check each user registered in names.nsf if it actually has access to Domino server.

Is there is an simple and programmatic way to find this out (I mean maybe some 2-4 tricky lines of code)?

Otherwise I guess I need to resolve (if defined) in server document [Security\Server Access] 'Access servers' and 'Not access server').

Answer (score 1):

Yes: „access server“ and „not access server“ are the places to look. Just look at the values. If there are groups in there, then you can check the group membership of the user with the admin- client and its „Manage Groups“ function where you can list all groups that a specific person belongs to.

Like this it is a question of just some clicks to check if somebody has access to a server or not.

„Not access server“ overwrites „access server“ here.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but if @Torsten's answer doesn't help, look at the @UserNamesList function.

For example, if you're doing analysis rather than doing this within an application, you could create a copy of the domain address book somewhere on your server (it needs to be on the server or @UserNamesList won't work, and you want to do it in a copy so you aren't dirtying up your domain address book because *wow* you are in trouble if you mess that up), then create a formula agent that runs on selected documents with code like:

```
GrantAccessGroups := "List of groups" : "that are allowed access";
DenyAccessGroups := "Deny Access" : "some other group" : "any other group" : "that is listed in the server's Server document's Deny Access field";
SELECT @IsMember(Form; "User" : "Person");
FIELD AccessCheckResult := @If(
  !@IsNotMember(@UserNamesList(FullName[1]); DenyAccessGroups); "Denied";
  !@IsNotMember(@UserNamesList(FullName[1]); GrantAccessGroups); "Confirmed";
  "Neither confirmed nor denied"
);
FIELD AccessCheckDate := @Now;
"Lotus Notes used to not like ending agent formulas with a FIELD statement, so this is just a string that does nothing just in case this quirk is still there :-P"
```

- I'm not sure if the form should be "User" or "Person". As long as I'm right about one or the other, though, `@IsMember(Form; "User" : "Person")` should work!
- @UserNamesList returns the name of all roles and groups for the given user.
- @IsNotMember is true only if there is no overlap between two lists. (If only some of the values in the second argument are in the first, both @IsNotMember **and** @IsMember return false, so you have to use !@IsNotMember.)
- Setting the AccessCheckDate is just for your own sanity in case things don't work quite right and you have to troubleshoot.

Once you run that, you can change your views to categorize by AccessCheckResult